# Django Testing - Accessing Site with authenticated user

Tags: django, django-tests

I am trying to do a unit test for authenticated user url access, currently I am trying to authenticate a user but I am unable to do so...

Test.py

```
def setUp(self):
    self.user = User.objects.create_user(email='test@testmail.com', password='test_password', is_staff=True)
    self.user.save()

    self.client = Client()

def test_portfolio_url(self):
    self.client.login(username='test@testmail.com', password='test_password')

    url = reverse('portfolio')
    response = self.client.get(url)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertEqual(resolve(url).func, portfolio)
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'portfolio.html')
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def portfolio(request, user_id=None):
    if user_id and request.user.is_staff:
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    else:
        ...
    return render(request, 'portfolio.html', {'portfolio': portfolio_data})
```

This is the response I suppose to get when logged in

[image: result to get]

Comment: can you provide any more information?  What errors are you seeing?  What is the response?  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may help.

Comment: the response I should get is 200 (page rendered), but I am receiving 302 (redirected due to user not authenticated)

Comment: your created user has no username (only email), but you try to login with username.

Answer (score 0):

- in `setUp()` you create a user with no username
- in `test_portfolio_url()` you try to login with a username, but use the email.
- in `setUp()`, you don't need to call `user.save()` - the [`create_user()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) call already saves the user

Comment: fixed the following, but I am still getting 302

Answer (score 0):

A bit late ,but I found solution for this maybe would be helpful for someone.. So I made function in the class for every test/view where the user needs to be authenticated and here it is.

```py
def login(self):
    self.username = 'test1'
    self.password = '12345qwe'
    user = ModelUser.objects.create_user(username=self.username)
    user.set_password(self.password)
    user.save()
    client = Client()
    client.login(username=self.username, password=self.password)
    return user, client
```

In the test you just need to call the function like this:

```
user, client = self.login()
```

So here you have already set up the user and the client and you can continue for example to take the response
response = client.get...
Of course you can improve the code as you like ,good luck!